# get the path of java file changed using IElementChangedListener

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am using `IElementChangedListener` to listen to changes in the Java Model in eclipse plug-in I am making.

Is there any way I can get the path of the java file that had the change using this Listener or should I try a different Listener?

Any suggestions or links are appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IJavaElementDelta` available in the `ElementChangedEvent` event has a `getElement()` method which returns an `IJavaElement`.

`IJavaElement` has a `getPath()` method which 'Returns the path to the innermost resource enclosing this element'.

You may have to look at the added / affected / changed children in the delta to get all changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
elementChangedListener.elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent event) {
    IJavaElementDelta delta = ElementChangedEvent.getDelta();
    int kind = delta.getKind();
    int flags = delta.getFlags();
    // flags -> F_ARCHIVE_CONTENT_CHANGED, F_ADDED_TO_CLASSPATH, F_CLASSPATH_REORDER, F_REMOVED_FROM_CLASSPATH
    if ((delta.getFlags() & IJavaElementDelta.F_ARCHIVE_CONTENT_CHANGED) != 0) {
        // The contents of an archive has changed in some way
    }
}
```

See documentation of [org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElementDelta](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIJavaElementDelta.html)